# regualr expression letters and word match

Tags: regex

apologies for what is probably a really simple question but I am a complete noob when it come to using regular expressions.

I am trying to create an expression that matches some set criteria together, and although I can find the code to validate these things separately I'm struggling to understand how you put it all together.

What I am looking for is an expression that validates an entered code:

It will always a start with either OR or TR and then you will have 6 digits after that e.g. TR002563

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[OT]R[0-9]{6}$/
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - it doesn't seem to have done the trick unfortunately, maybe I should have been more specific that this is for a Google doc online form (not sure if this makes a difference)

Comment: You need to use it without `/` then like: `^[OT]R[0-9]{6}$`

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
/^(?:O|T)R[0-9]{6}$/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks for your reply - it doesn't seem to have done the trick unfortunately, maybe I should have been more specific that this is for a Google doc online form (not sure if this makes a difference)

Comment: Remove the `/` when you type the regex. Usually, when an OP posts a question about regex, she precises its flavour (ie java, C#, php etc). This helps answerers providing better responses. Since there is no flavor, anubhava and I provided the an agnostic flavor answer. The first `/` and last `/` are respectively the beginning and the end of the regexp.